# RangeError: private key length is invalid

Tags: private-key, ethereumjs

I am trying to sign a message using the following code:`ethJsUtil.ecsign(ethJsUtil.sha256(msg),new Buffer('0x...'))`

Where 0x... is my private key taken from MyEtherWallet. It gives the error in the title both with and without the 0x at the beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ethJsUtil.ecsign(ethJsUtil.sha256(msg),ethJsUtil.toBuffer('0x...'))` works.
`new Buffer` was returning an empty buffer

Answer (score 0):

Basically you pasted:

```
node ./keygen.js 0xdd0c9ec256a7e76a6693a0d2dea01a6de6b7dfeaf3afcaef7b95647758c79c1a
```

Instead of:

```
node ./keygen.js dd0c9ec256a7e76a6693a0d2dea01a6de6b7dfeaf3afcaef7b95647758c79c1a
```

Comment: Please explain the relevance of this answer. It's been flagged by two different users and I reluctantly will clean this up if it gets another flag.