# RangeError: private key length is invalid (In New ETH Transaction pragmatically)

Tags: web3js, transactions, ether, raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

Followed this Ans
[Ans1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/19576/rangeerror-private-key-length-is-invalid) and [Ans2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/55038/ethereum-transaction-rangeerror-private-key-length-is-invalid) but no solution got.

```
const web3 = new Web3('https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/3c52917848e945229c0d33d632b10490');

const account1 = '0x0982081d5a2bba0a9da9fe722c92edc0cb0e9b6a'
const account2 = '0xabc46ddc17a0c37ef70e8a153d4724f199705e8b'

const ac1_pvtkey =Buffer.from('XXXX9F79B587B1DE553E2ADCA3DC8D49BE3E2840083D970C41D83F7FD471XXXX');

const ac2_pvtkey =Buffer.from('XXXXC15FBDB4634400B7F8FA17C9491B2E346AEC1BC86A493B18F5759042XXXX');
```

> //build transaction here ---------------------------

```
 `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account2, (err, txCount) => {
    const txObject = {
    nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to: account2,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('0.2','ether')),
    gaslimit: web3.utils.toHex(2100),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei'))
    }
```

console.log(txObject)

> //signing transaction here ---------------------------

```
const tx = new Tx(txObject);
tx.sign(ac2_pvtkey); //using account2 private key
```

> ------------------------- ERROR GIVING ------------------------

```
var sig = secp256k1.sign(msgHash, privateKey);
                    ^
RangeError: private key length is invalid `
```

Comment: is the private key 32 bytes  long ?

Comment: or 64 character hex string?

Comment: @Nulik yes, I changed 5 address & keys

Answer (score 4):

> **Answer to my question**

```
//Admin's eth Address ------------
const account1 = process.env.ADMIN_ETH_ADDR;
//Admin's eth private key -----------------
const ac1_pvtkey = Buffer.from(process.env.ADMIN_ETH_PVT_KEY, 'hex');
```

> Actual Transaction creation -> signing tx -> serializing tx -> Getting
>   Transaction hash

```
 var txnCount = web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1);

      var txObject = {
          nonce: web3.toHex(txnCount),
          gasPrice: web3.toHex(100000000000),
          gasLimit: web3.toHex(140000),
          to: to, //to is ETH address-----
          value: web3.toHex(web3.toWei(amount,'ether')),//amount to be send----
          data: '0xcfa'
      };

      try{

          var transaction = new tx(txObject);
          transaction.sign(ac1_pvtkey);

          var serializedTx = transaction.serialize();

          console.log(serializedTx.toString('hex'));
          transactionId = web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'));

          console.log(transactionId);

      } catch (e) {
          return console.error(e);
          console.log("Error ETH Transaction ");
      }
```

**Hope this helps. Thanks**

Answer (score 2):

Do not use with 'Ox' Remove those in privatekey